# bitwise shift operator seems to wrap?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

This is Windows 7 32-bit, Visual Studio 2017, in a C file.

```
int i = 65536;
```

As expected,

```
i >> 0 = 65536
i >> 1 = 32768
  :
  :
i >> 16 = 1
i >> 17 to 31 = 0.
```

i >> 32 is magically 65536 again though.  How is that legal?

ISO/IEC 9899:TC2 says the following and I assume C++ specs are the same?

> The result of E1 >> E2 is E1 right-shifted E2 bit positions. **If E1 has
>   an unsigned type or if E1 has a signed type and a nonnegative value,
>   the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of E1 /
>   2^E2.** If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value
>   is implementation-defined.

Comment: The relevant quote from the standard should be the one about shifting more than the number of bits of the left-hand operand.

Comment: There's not a lot of magic there, in some other languages this behaviour is even *mandatory*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[6.5.7p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7p3)

> ... If the value of the right operand is negative or is **greater than
>   or equal to the width of the promoted left operand**, the behavior is
>   **undefined**.

With clang, gcc, and icc, you'll [get a warning](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/CHEHPG) if you attempt to shift by a constant that's greater or equal to the width of the shifted value, and you don't even need any extra command-line flags.

Comment: OK, then, that's a horrible spec, though, to make an unqualified statement about what the value is (that I quoted), then have a qualification in another paragraph.  Why the heck didn't they just put a table of situations and results, I wonder.

Comment: @SwissFrank The (or a) reason is because different CPUs have different behavior, e.g., on x86-32bit only the last 5bits of the shift count are used. That means it would require some additional comparison/branching/masking, if this was to be implemented platform-independent. Since C (and C++) seeks to be a zero-overhead language, things like this are rather left undefined (or implementation defined).